# Thick guitar cable

Tags: cable

I just bought a few 1/4'' plugs from Switchcraft - I want to assemble my custom short cables in order to connect the effects on my pedalboard.

The hole in the plug handle has a diameter of 0.297'' (about 7.5 mm). My problem is that I have been unable to locate a screened cable with such a big (outer) diameter.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Find a piece of plastic tubing, cut it longitudinally,if needed, and put it over the cable coming out of the plug, About 25mm will do. The plugs are better for pedals if they're right-angled. Also, you can't pull them out by the wire, a favourite trick guitarists seem to have.

Answer (score 2):

Screened cable comes in various sizes.  But it doesn't HAVE to fill the exit hole.  The strain is taken at the clamp inside the plug.

Not that there should BE much strain between items on a pedalboard.  Maybe you chose unnecessarily robust plugs.

Comment: Typo or do you actually think there _should_ be much strain on the patch cables? I do not think so; nevertheless it is certainly a good idea to err on the sturdy side for connectors, since a pedalboard is seldom a static affair...

Comment: No typo.  What I wrote means 'there shouldn't BE much strain...'  Connectors shouldn't be unnecessarily heavy or bulky.  There's a danger of making the socket on the pedal the weakest point.  You don't want THAT failing.

Answer (score 2):

I have a suggestion for a potentially easier way to solve your dilemma and accomplish your goal. It's probably less expensive as well. Perhaps you have already explored this solution and found it lacking = but I will post the information just in case you or a future reader of your question might benefit from it.

Why not order the fully assembled patch cables made specifically for pedalboards from some place such as **[Sweetwater Music](http://www.sweetwater.com/c635--Pedal_and_Effects_Accessories)** where you can get the entire assembly already put together for less than $4.00 (US) per cable if purchased in packs of 3 or more.  Most are 6 inch long but they have varying configurations, and gauges.  Two examples are pictured below.  The link above will take you to the right page on the Sweetwater Music Website.  Good luck with your pedal project!

[image]

[image]